# Weak derivative of $|x|^\alpha$ in $\mathbb{R}^N \setminus \{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

I want to generalize the fact that the weak derivative of $|x|$ is $sgn(x)$.

The expected result should be $\frac{d|x|^{\alpha}}{dx_i} = \alpha x_i |x|^{\alpha - 2}$. A way to do this is found in page 50 of [these notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch3.pdf).

However, I don't have the tools to believe that:

> $|x|^{\alpha}$ is weakly differentiable provided that the pointwise derivative,
>   which is defined almost everywhere, is locally integrable

So I would like to do it without using this fact.

**The domain**

I think weak derivatives have a dependence on the domain so I specify that I want the derivative of $|x|^{\alpha}$ in $\mathbb{R}^N \setminus \{0\}$

**The computation**

$\int |x|^{\alpha} \frac{d\phi}{dx_i} d(x_1,\ldots,x_N)$, $\phi \in \mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}$, by Fubini's theorem (?) I can write:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N-1} \setminus \{0\}} (\int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}} |x|^{\alpha} \frac{d\phi}{dx_i} dx_i) d(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},x_N)$

integrating by parts $\int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}} |x|^{\alpha} \frac{d\phi}{dx_i} dx_i$ and using that $\phi \in \mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}$:

$\int_{-\infty}^0 |x|^{\alpha} \frac{d\phi}{dx_i} dx_i = 
-\int_{-\infty}^0 \alpha x_i |x|^{\alpha-2} \phi dx_i$, analogously, $\int_{0}^\infty |x|^{\alpha} \frac{d\phi}{dx_i} dx_i = 
-\int_{0}^\infty \alpha x_i |x|^{\alpha-2} \phi dx_i$

so that I get the result equal to:

$-\int_{\mathbb{R}^N \setminus \{0\}} \alpha x_i|x|^{\alpha}\phi dx_i$

The only thing to finish the proof would be to see where I missed the - sign.

Comment: The distributional derivative of $T$ is defined as $$\frac{\partial T}{\partial x_i}[\varphi] = -T\biggl[\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_i}\biggr]\,.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, you're right. the rest of steps is correct?

Comment: indeed i don't think the integration limits are correct